# Odd (Slow) Behaviour in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

First off I would like to apologize beforehand, in case this turns out to be a really dumb question.  I just can't wrap my head around it.

I have a C# ASP.NET website running with .net 2.0
Both on my local machine, as well as on production server it runs terribly slow.

Even if I disable ALL the code, it still runs slow to serve the page.

However, if it is a .ashx, instead of a .aspx it executes immediately; even if it executes the same things.

Any ideas?
Truly appreciated!

Comment: Please note, that there is an overwhelming amount of memory available, and it is regardless of traffic to the server(s)

Comment: I have also tested with RedGate ANTS performance profiler and NOTHING.  I suspect some sort of iis issue maybe?

Comment: Have you tried running the profile after the first view of the aspx page, since on the first view after deployment you have to worry about compilation time?  So load the page once, start the profile, and then load the page again.  Do the same for your ashx file, just to be sure you're comparing apples to apples.

Comment: In the web.config, are there any custom HttpModules configured for asp pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if your ashx page loads faster than the aspx, it might be related to the HttpModules or aspx page lifecycle custom code running on your application.

Check if you have anything in the Application_BeginRequest or other events in the lifecycle that could be writing to files (logs), connecting to slow databases or a authentication authority (like AD) that might be going thru the network and taking longer than usual to process.

Disable all the HttpModules in the web.config one by one and test. Check [this great article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/10ASPNetPerformance.aspx) to get more info

Comment: was just about to post that article by Omar !!

Comment: I have completely disabled the _BeginRequest, and actually the whole of the global.asax and no difference.  I am looking at the httpModules article now - Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if this is actually the answer, but I'm giving you the checkmark (at least for now) because the article is godsend.

Answer (score 1):

Are your .aspx pages defined as content pages for a Master page? Perhaps there is logic being executed in the Master.

Comment: Yes, and I have disabled the master page, and executed the page without the master page.  This gives a faster result, by half even, but again, slow slow slow.

Maybe like 15 seconds before even starting to return a response to browser.

Comment: The ANTS profiler seems always to move into the NATIVE parts of the code.  HTMLWriter etc

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating a new, quick Website on your local server to test the speed?  Try creating a quick asp.net website and test it on the local server.  If this new website goes fast, it may be something within your existing website that you're not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any difference between the inbuild development server and your iis server?

Comment: one is 64bit iis7, the other is 32bit iis6
problem exists on both.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a slow javascript?  Ajax request?  Is botht he asjx and aspx doing the same things?